# How to extend SELinux policy to allow ntpd to use gps?

Tags: centos, selinux, ntpd

There is an attached device on the motherboard and the `NTP` service tries to read data from it (the attached device link is in `/dev` directory). Using SELinux `enforcing`, the service status errors that it has not permission to access the device. Setting SELinux to `disabled`, solve the problem but it's not the standrad way to do that.

I know someone should create a new SELinux policy in such situations. Assuming the `NTP` service tries to read `/dev/gps0`, can somebody give an example on how to write a SELinux rule for that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what label is applied to `/dev/gps0` (you can view using `ls -Z /dev/gps0`)?

Comment: @sebasth `lrwxrwxrwx root root ?                                /dev/gps0 -> ttyUSB0`

Comment: You should use SELinux in permissive mode, instead of disabling it. In permissive mode rules are not enforced, but logs are generated. Can you [enable](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-changing_selinux_modes#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Enabling_SELinux-) SELinux in permissive mode and check the label again? (I recommend checking the link before you proceed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when dealing with SELinux and standard services included in RHEL/CentOS distribution, you should first read the appropriate `<servicename>_selinux` man page.

In this case, on RHEL 7 at least, ntpd's SELinux policy includes SELinux file type label `gpsd_tmpfs_t`, which suggests that the policy might have built-in support for `ntpd` communicating with GPS devices via `gpsd`. Setting up `gpsd` and then communication between it and `ntpd` might be the way to keep the tightest possible SELinux policy while using a GPS device with `ntpd`.

Alternatively, you can use `semanage permissive -a ntpd_t` to switch SELinux to permissive mode **for the** `ntpd` **process only.**

When in permissive mode, you can then find the messages referring to /dev/gps0 or /dev/ttyUSB0 in the audit logs (see `/var/log/audit`) and feed them to the `audit2allow` tool. It should tell you the exact SELinux policy changes needed to allow ntpd to access the GPS device directly.

Comment: Thanks, I found this in `audit.log` file: `type=AVC msg=audit(1538395083.420:527): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=19160 comm="ntpd" name="ttyUSB0" dev="devtmpfs" ino=60814 scontext=system_u:system_r:ntpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usbtty_device_t:s0 tclass=chr_file`. How can I use it to apply on SELinux policy?

Comment: You can use `audit2allow` as explained in the answer.

Comment: After the command `semanage permissive -a ntpd_t`, how can I revert SELinux settings for `ntpd`? I tried `semanage enforcing -a ntpd_t` but it didn't work!

Comment: To remove the type-specific permissive setting, use `semanage permissive -d ntpd_t`. See `man semanage-permissive` for details.